# Use of uninitialized value $login_output in concatenation (.) or string at

Tags: perl

in a .pl I have the following error (capture), the script is used through SPECTRUM, a network monitoring tool, and the script is used to capture the running config of a device, what could be the fault ? Thank you.

[image]

```
    #!/opt/SPECTRUM/bin/perl -w

 

  # This script will capture the running configuration of a

  # Cisco SAN-OS device through an SSH session and print it to STDOUT.

  #

  # Error Codes:

  #   0   = Success

  #   255 = Usage error

  #   254 = Invalid timeout value

  #   252 = Login error

  #   249 = Exec prompt not found error

  #   244 = Error retrieving configuration

  #   245 = Insufficient privileges

  #   253 = Unexpected output

  #

 

  use strict;

  use warnings;

  use Net::SSH::Expect;

 

  $ENV{'PATH'} = "/usr/bin:". $ENV{'PATH'};

 

  ### Main ###

  if( $#ARGV != 4 && $#ARGV != 5 )

  {

      print "Usage: capture_running.pl <device IP> <user> <pass> <enable_pass>

  <login_timeout_in_seconds> <capture_timeout_in_seconds>\n";

      print STDERR "Usage:  capture_running.pl <deviceIP> <user> <pass>

  <enable_pass> <login_timeout_in_seconds> <capture_timeout_in_seconds>\n";

      exit 255;

  }

  elsif( $ARGV[4] < 1 || $ARGV[4] > 600 )

  {

      print "$ARGV[4] is the login timeout and must be an int between 1 and 600  seconds\n";

      print STDERR "$ARGV[4] is the login timeout and must be an int between 1 and  600 seconds\n";

      exit 254;

  }

  elsif( $#ARGV == 5 && ( $ARGV[5] < 1 || $ARGV[5] > 600 ) )

  {

      print "$ARGV[5] is the capture timeout and must be an int between 1 and 600  seconds\n";

      print STDERR "$ARGV[5] is the capture timeout and must be an int between 1  and 600 seconds\n";

      exit 254;

  }

  else

  {

      my $capture_timeout = $ARGV[4];

      if( $ARGV[5] )

      {

         $capture_timeout = $ARGV[5];

      }

 

      my $errorCode = 1;

      my @data;

      my $errorString = "\nHost $ARGV[0]:  \n";

 

      ($errorCode, @data) = GetConfig( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2], $ARGV[3],

                                       $ARGV[4], $capture_timeout );

 

      if( $errorCode == 0 )

      {

          # Success.  The running configuration

          # content is in the data variable

 

          foreach ( @data ) { print "$_\n" }; # print the configuration to STDOUT

          exit 0;

      }

      else

      {

          print STDERR $errorString;

 

          if( $errorCode == 245 )

          {

              print STDERR join " ", @data, "\nEnsure that the device user has

  sufficient privileges to disable paging and view the config\n";

          }

          else

          {

              print STDERR join " ", @data, "\n";

          }

 

          exit $errorCode;

      }

  }

 

  exit 0;

 

  sub GetConfig

  {

  my $deviceIP=shift;

  my $user=shift;

  my $pass=shift;

  my $epass=shift;

  my $login_timeout=shift;

  my $capture_timeout=shift;

  my @config;

  my $msg;

 

  my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new ( host => $deviceIP,

                                    user => $user,

                                    password=> $pass,

                                    raw_pty => 1,

                                    no_terminal => 0,

                                    timeout => $login_timeout,

  ssh_option => '-1 -c DES'

                                  );

 

  my $login_output;

  eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };

  

  if( $@ )

  {

      $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";

      return( 252, $msg );

  }

 

  # login output should contain the right prompt characters

  if( $login_output !~ /\>\s*\z/ )

  {

      $msg = "Login has failed. Didn't see device prompt as expected.";

      $ssh->close();

      return( 252, $msg );

  }

 

  if( $login_output !~ /\>\s*\z/ )  # Replace '#' is the prompt character here

  {

  #     we don't have the '#' prompt, means we still can't exec commands

        $msg = "Exec prompt not found.";

        $ssh->close();

        return( 249, $msg );

  }

  

    my $elogin = $ssh->exec("en");

  

    my $elogin2 = $ssh->exec($epass);

  

 

 

    if( $elogin2 !~ /\#\s*\z/ )  # Replace '#' is the prompt character here

    {

      $msg = "Exec prompt not found.";

        $ssh->close();

        return( 249, $msg );

    }

 

 

  # disable paging

  # different commands for different devices, if they don't

  # work then we will get messages about problems later

  # specifically the "No prompt after 'sh run'" error

  # errmsg doesn't get set when these error and if we use print

  # and getlines to read for errors it causes problems with print "sh run"

  # later.

  # $ssh->exec( "term pager 0" );

  my $paging = $ssh->exec( "term pager 0" );

  if ( $paging =~  /\s?%\s/ )

  {

      $msg = "Unable to set terminal size to 0 - Insufficient privileges";

      $ssh->close();

          return( 245, $msg);

  }

 

  $ssh->send( "sh run" );

  $ssh->timeout( $capture_timeout );

  $ssh->peek(0);

 

  while( my $line = $ssh->read_line() )

  {

      # get configuration content

 

      if( $line !~

          /sh run|Building configuration|Current configuration|^\s*$/ )

      {

          push @config, $line;

      }

  }

 

  if( @config <= 0 )

  {

      $msg = "No data retrieved, the capture timeout may be too low.";

      $ssh->close();

      return( 244, $msg );

  }

 

  if( scalar grep { $_ =~ /^%/ } @config )

  {

      # Ensure show running actually returned the config and not an error

      # message containing '%'

      return( 245, @config );

  }

 

  return( 0, @config ); # everything was okay, return the captured data

  }
```

Comment: You need to work on formatting your code. There's support for code blocks in the editor. I suggest that you click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66533491/edit) and fix that. I made a small improvement to it, but you need to fix the indentation etc yourself.

Comment: What line is the problem at? What is at that line?

Comment: I had a quick look and `$msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";` looks like the culprit. Try removing `$login_output` from that line`.

Comment: Or add `$@` to that line to see how your login attempt failed.

Comment: The part of the message about "uninitialized value" is only a warning that `$login_output` was not defined.  That isn't why the script failed.  The failure is because it could not log into the device.  Now the type of login failure could be why `$login_output` didn't get a value though.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely candidate for that error is this:

```
my $login_output;

eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };

if( $@ )
{
    $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";      # this line
    return( 252, $msg );
}
```

Remove `$login_output` from that line since it will be uninitialized if `login()` `die`s/`croak`s. You can replace it with `$@` to get the message supplied to `die`/`croak`.

Comment: Actually, there's not a single call to `die()` in the whole program :-)

Comment: @DaveCross I suspect it's in `login()`. It may be a `croak` or similar I guess :)  Looking at the `Net::SSH::Expect` example makes me wonder though.

Comment: The code that's failing is in a subroutine called `GetConfig`. When the login fails, that subroutine returns an error code and a string. The string is output using `print STDERR` (which should probably be replaced with `warn()`) and the program exits with the error code.

Comment: @DaveCross There are 5 `croak`s in (my version of) `login`, I suspect it's one of those or possibly in some other `sub` called from `login`.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help us if you took the time to ensure the code you give us is well-formatted and as easy to read as possible.

But the code causing the problem is this:

```
my $login_output;

eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };



if( $@ )

{

    $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";

    return( 252, $msg );

}
```

It's the only place where `$login_output` is used in a "concatenation (.) or string" as described in the error message.

So the the call to `$ssh->login()` is failing in such a way as to leave `$login_output` undefined.

I don't know anything about [Net::SSH::Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect), but I suspect that you need to change the arguments to the `new()` call (a few lines above) in some way.

You'll get more information about what has gone wrong by adding `$@` to the debug output.